# ListView selection does not change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

In my app I have activity which contains two fragments.

The first fragment contains ViewPager which contains a few fragments(the first fragment of viewpager fragments contains ListView). The second fragment is simple settings fragment. For example, I have checked the second element on the ListView, I click settings and my second fragment from activity opens. I click back button and I go back to my ListView, then I call :

```
listView.setItemChecked(0, true);
listView.setSelection(0);
```

But this does not work, the second element is still checked...
I go from ViewPager to the second fragment in below way:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.slpdActivityLayout, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Why my selection does not work only when I press back button?

Comment: Do you have singleselection on?

Comment: "the second element is still checked" - is the first element checked too? if yes: then just unchecked the second (all others in a loop)
if no: maybe you need to refresh the UI

Comment: Yes, like this `AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`

Comment: no, only the second element is checked

Comment: then check, if the view has to be updated - maybe with `isDirty()`
and check programmaticly if the second element is checked

Comment: When do you call this code? It maybe be called before Fragment restores state, and ListView restores selection

Comment: I call this code in `onCreateView` method from Fragment which contains ListView...

Comment: maybe im wrong here but your code isnt executing becuase your first view was already created and you didnt get in `onCreateView` again.
place your code into `onResume()`

Comment: Yes, my code in `onResume` works ;) Could you explain me this?

Comment: It's about the lifecycle of your fragment like seen here http://i.stack.imgur.com/cJ3QW.png
in your case with the back button, the view is always created so `onCreateView` isnt calling anymore. BUT `onResume` is. I'll post an answer now

Comment: But I'm debugging my code and `onCreateView' method is calling the second time...

Comment: then you maybe create a second instance of the first which isnt visable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about the lifecycle of your fragment like seen [-> here <-](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_1_-_creating_a_fragment/Images/fragment_lifecycle.png)  you cant do UI updates in `onCreateView`. so place your code to `onStart` or better `onResume`.

remove:

```
public void onCreateView() {
    listView.setItemChecked(0, true);
    listView.setSelection(0);
}
```

add:

```
public void onResume() {
    listView.setItemChecked(0, true);
    listView.setSelection(0);
}
```

Comment: So when I call `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.slpdActivityLayout, secondFragment).addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();` in the activity fragment with the listView isn't destroyed? I thing that is destroyed...

Comment: you can easily check it with debugging the `onDestroy` or `onDestroyView` method of the fragment

Comment: fragment with the listView is destroyed... so why this code does not work in 'onCreateView' method?

Comment: yeah it makes sense. sorry. the right answer was too obvious. changed my answer.

Comment: so why this code does not work in 'onCreateView' method?